# Loading questions of a quiz

Tags: ios

How do I know how much memory does say some dictionary take?

I am asking this for following reasons.

I may have a dictionary with three keys and objects. Here is a sample of my dictionary.

```
One Dictionary (sample)
---------

key:"questionPath" Object:"image1.png"
key:"correctAnswer" Object:"1"
key:"totalAnswers" Object:"6"
```

This dictionary represents a single quiz question as you might guess in the app I was thinking to write.

Since there maybe 1000 questions I may need to load these 1000 dictionaries from a plist to array. (and then query questions one by one out of the array).

Do you think this would consume too much memory?

When images are loaded like resources in the project, shall I just use their names when referring from code? (like in my sample above)

Comment: Yes it will put a dent in your memory depending to how you write your code you can avoid that.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey: Well how much of a dent will it put? Like I said this maybe just array of 1000 dictionaries loaded from plist. Each dictionary may have I think at most three keys and their values.

Comment: I would not load images.

Comment: @user523234: Hi thanks for response. Images aren't loaded like I said, the dictionary just contains path to the image. The questions in my quiz are embedded in the image, I can't avoid that. (The image will be loaded when a turn of some question occurs only)

Comment: try using something other than plist. maybe sqlite or core data. 1000 entries, 1000 images in your project. thats a big app and even though you are referencing the images, it will have to load and unload. as i said try building your project and plug in 100 entries and see the memory out put. then add another 100 and compare. if you are happy with the memory consumption then go for it. for a project that size sqlite is more reliable. at least that is what i think.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey: I'll try. I am estimating each Dictionary should not take more than 50 bytes, than that's 50000 bytes of memory. (SQLite and CoreData need learning, I don't want to do that now, if its not necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple app and create a loop that creates 1000 identical objects (using the same values as you listed above). Add those objects to a collection such as NSMutableArray so they persist. Then check the memory usage with Instruments. This gives you a rough idea of the memory needs of the app when all questions are loaded into memory.

You will probably only access a small subset of the questions at a given time. A more efficient solution would leave question data in the filesystem until actually needed in memory. CoreData is one solution Apple provides for this. Or you could use NSCoder and store each question in its own binary file for a simpler, scalable, memory-efficient implementation.

Here's is the Apple documentation for the NSCoder class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html

That page includes links to sample code.

Think of NSCoder as a straightforward way to save a collection (e.g. NSArray, NSDictionary) to disk, or load it from disk. So in your case, you could have a file called question1.data up to question1000.data, and NSCoder provides an easy interface for loading that data when needed. Just be sure to discard the question data when it is no longer needed or your app will always grow its memory usage and never shrink it.

Comment: Storing each question separately would make more sense (I am not familiar with Core data and I don't think can spend time on learning that now). But when storing each question separately, initializing them would be more cumbersome I think.... How would I initialize them?? (That said if the first approach - the one I mentioned - does not take too much memory, why not go for it? It maybe easier for me to implement; and how much memory would 1000*dictionary take that iPhone can't handle, I doubt ... )

Comment: iOS is an environment where memory is a precious, limited resource that must be shared with other apps. If your app is using an excessive amount of memory and is unable to free memory when asked to do so, your app will be terminated by a watchdog process. Since you describe your app as a quiz with 1000 questions, my belief is you should use a data strategy that only loads a small subset of the questions into memory.

Comment: It is true that CoreData takes a good amount of effort to learn and implement, and may not be necessary in your case. I'll update the answer with more detail on using NSCoder.

Comment: I understand but if the memory I consume with my approach is negligible as compared to the available memory, I think I would prefer my initial approach

Comment: Thanks yes NSCoder is other approach (I also thought about this). But this way I would have to hard code first Question objects in code and then write all of them to the file system right? (For initialization)

Comment: Having 1k files will generate too many I/O operations... If you go for `NSCoding` do the array/dict approach instead of that many separate files

Comment: Yes you would need to create the questions and store them to disk in advance. This can be done with a separate app. NSCoder gives you the flexibility to store any number of quiz questions in a single file. If you have quizzes that are the same five or ten questions every time, you can make one file per quiz rather than one file per question. Or if your quiz will randomly select a question from among the same three questions each time, put those three questions together in a file. You do this by nesting collections, e.g. an NSArray of NSDictionaries.

Comment: @atxe: "If you go for NSCoding do the array/dict approach "-I am not sure I followed what you mean here? Bneely - there maybe 1000 questions in the app but for a single quiz, I may need to draw 30 random questions (I know how to draw them randomly, question was about storage) - I am also not sure I got your last post fully.... thanks

Comment: If you are concerned with having 1000 question files in your app, you can group multiple questions into one file. For example you could have questions 1-10 in one file, 11-20 in the next file, etc. The NSCoder approach is flexible. You can use one file, 1000 files, or some number in between.

Comment: @bneely: It's a matter of accessing them. With 1000 files I thought, ok, I will generate random int from 1 to 1000 - what comes out, I will fetch proper file? If I group them hmm.. Could do it by generating random number twice, e.g., first time for the group (if I have ten groups 1,...,10) and then to get question out of that group... ?

Comment: The code to choose the correct file of question groups is fairly straightforward to write. I would suggest you start a new question though if you want to explore that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the memory usage using the profiler. In Xcode: Product > Profile. Then check `Allocations`. Anyway, even if it fits, having everything in memory is not scalable, so I'd think about a `CoreData` approach, that will keep your memory usage much slower.

Comment: What do you mean not scalable? How much memory would 1000 * dictionary consume? Isn't there enough memory for that on iPhone? (I already mentioned the kind of dictionary it maybe)

Comment: I mean that if tomorrow you add 1000 extra records It will use around the double of memory, and so on. I mean, with that implementation you are limiting the potential growth of your data. But, that might not be important at the moment ;-) I'd expect 1MB at most. But, as mentioned, I'd suggest you to try to load the dictionaries on memory and pass the profiler, so you can decide if you can afford it.

Comment: I will check with profiler thanks. Was just inquiring I doubt my single dictionary will take more than 50 bytes (just a guess :)) so in total that is 50 000 bytes of memory, I think that should be ok for iphone isn't it? (but I'll try with profiler thanks)

Comment: Yeah... well... I don't like to make that lower estimations... just in case... :) Gotta take memory alignment, runtime stuff and so on in consideration :) If it's 50k bytes it will be more than ok for an iPhone ;)

Comment: Hey atxe you say 1000*dictionary could take at most 1MB. How much memory available do I have then? (1MB is really upper bound but ok)

Comment: I will depend on the device you run it, the OS version and the current memory consumption. But do not worry. As a nice practice, try to not exceed ~12-14MB.

Comment: thanks. So dictionary array shouldn't be that much issue in my case I think. (Though indeed storing questions on file system and only loading those that I need might make more sense- like suggested below, but I will see..... dictionary approach seemed faster for me to implement)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48252/discussion-between-atxe-and-dmcr-code)